# New Mexico's Governor issues emergency suspending constitutional rights

Tags: constitutional-law, firearms, new-mexico, emergencies, constitutional-rights

https://apnews.com/article/albuquerque-guns-governor-concealed-carry-fc5b4b79bf411b8022c3ad58975724d7

> New Mexico Gov. Michelle Lujan Grisham on Friday issued an emergency order suspending the right to carry firearms in public across Albuquerque and the surrounding county for at least 30 days in response to a spate of gun violence.

Is there an emergency exception to the constitution that allows a states governor to suspend constitutional rights?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Did New Mexico's govenor break any laws with her emergancy order suspending gun rights?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/95360/did-new-mexicos-govenor-break-any-laws-with-her-emergancy-order-suspending-gun)

Comment: No they are different questions. One is asking if she broke any laws, the other is asking whether there is an exception to constitutional rights during an emergency declaration.

Comment: That question doesn't have any answers, so it seems pretty unlikely to answer this question.